Add attribute table in QGIS layout with more than one attribute table as source
I have two attribute tables
Table "monthly Inspection"



item
date




A
2024-01-01


A
2024-02-01


B
2024-01-01


B
2024-02-01



Table "yearly Inspection"



item
date




A
2022-06-01


A
2023-06-01


B
2022-06-01


B
2023-06-01



and I want to create a table in Layout with the following structure:
Inspections Item A



type
date




yearly Inspection
2022-06-01


yearly Inspection
2023-06-01


monthly Inspection
2024-01-01


monthly Inspection
2024-02-01



So to speak I want to virtually join these two tables and filter out one item.
Is this somehow possible to do (without actually joining the tables)?

So you're asking how to do a join without doing a join? Why not just do a join?

Actually i want a union, sorry for the confusion. Ans yes. Im asking for a union without doing a union. Its the people working with the tables are not experienced users of qgis.

You're actually looking for a UNION rather than a JOIN.
You can do this virtually by creating a new virtual layer (Create Layer->New Virtual Layer), and using the following SQL to populate the layer:
select 'monthly Inspection' as [type], date from [monthly Inspection] where item = 'A'
union all
select 'yearly Inspection', date from [yearly Inspection] where item = 'A'


Results:


You are completly right, union is the right term. But your solution won't work for me because of:

The tables I work with are huge. So there are not two item but hundreds so a union could only be performed automatically.
The tables are filled on daily basis by users not very experienced with qgis. They know how to edit an layer and fill in the data with attribute forms. Than they open a layout a click Print. Thats it.
But I like the idea of the virtual layer. I can union the two layer with a new field [type] and than filter the item i need in print composer with the @atlasfeatureid


Keep in mind that Virtual Layers can slow down on large data sets. But also keep in mind that you're asking about question X, when your actual problem is Y (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). It makes it tricky to give you an answer that's going to work. Remember to include the broader picture in your question even if you provide a cut down sample data set.
